# Select case with formulated cell NOT WORKING

Tags: excel, vba, select, case

I have the cell "cModelBoolean" in my worksheet which is calculated by formula into a Boolean.

I'm trying to base a select case function based on this cell. If the cell value = True then display MsgBox.

I have no idea why this isn't working!! See my code below

```
Option Explicit

Private cModelBoolean As Range

Private Sub DefineRangeVariables()

    Set cModelBoolean = Me.Range("_cModelBoolean")

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call DefineRangeVariables

    Select Case Target.Address

        Case cModelBoolean.Address
        
            Select Case cModelBoolean
            
                Case Is = True
            
                    MsgBox "True"
                    
                Case Is = False
                
                    MsgBox "False"
                    
            End Select

    End Select

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: No need for either select or if: `Msgbox = cModelBoolean.value`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call DefineRangeVariables

    Select Case Target.Address
        Case cModelBoolean.Address
            MsgBox cModelBoolean
            ' ..or if you want MsgBox only when True, as you state...
            If cModelBoolean Then MsgBox cModelBoolean
        ' ... all other cases
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That does seem to work but only if I type in the cell "True", doesn't work when the cell calculates TRUE based on a formula.